# How to get the original click date of the photo using Instagram API

Tags: date, instagram, photo

I am using Instagram API and I need to get the original click date of the photo. Currently Instagram API give me the date the photo was uploaded to Instagram, but not the original click date. This an issue since it changes the meaning of the actual context of the photo.

Is there a way I can get the original date on which the photo was taken?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the original click date and uploaded date same when then photo is clicked from inside the app? And if you are allowing a feature to add photos from gallery then there is no original photo only its instagrammed version exists. 
ie: The original photo is stored in gallery location and the new photo after editing is stored in instagram folder or app folder. 
The is no relation between the original and edited photo. So getting the date of creation of one file from another unrelated file is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the date date the photo was taken :-(

Instagram does not expose it via their api.

In my opinion this is short sited from instagram.

The date taken is stored in the image.

It can not be that difficult the save the correct date from the image, all the info is there.